# How to link .so library on Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I'm trying to use FFMpeg with Android. First of all I have tryed to build FFMpeg on my Mac but I cant do that. I checked many solution on Internet but none working. Becouse of that I try to  build FFMpeg on Ubuntu 12.04. I try a lot of solutions bu finally I found [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/blogs/2013/12/06/building-ffmpeg-for-android-on-x86) example and I succeed build it. Then I get headers files and .so files. Then I copy all of them on my mac and try to use it in my project. I copy this files to my project. Now my project tree looks like this:

[picture](http://postimg.org/image/86sd6cx0z/)

Here is my Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := avformat
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libavformat.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/libavformat
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := ndksetup
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Here is my Application.mk file:

```
APP_MODULES := ndksetup
APP_PLATFORM := android-8
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libavformat.so
```

Here is my natice.c file:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include "include/libavcodec/avcodec.h"
#include "include/libavformat/avformat.h"

#define DEBUG_TAG "NDKSetupActivity"

void Java_com_example_ndksetup_MainActivity_printLog(JNIEnv *env, jobject this,
        jstring logString) {
    av_register_all();
    jboolean isCopy;
    const char * szLogString = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, logString,
            &isCopy);

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "NDK: %s", szLogString);

    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, logString, szLogString);
}

jint Java_com_example_ndksetup_MainActivity_fibonacci(JNIEnv * env,
        jobject this, jint value) {
    if (value <= 1)
        return value;
    return Java_com_example_ndksetup_MainActivity_fibonacci(env, this,
            value - 1)
            + Java_com_example_ndksetup_MainActivity_fibonacci(env, this,
                    value - 2);
}
```

I get error

```
[armeabi] SharedLibrary  : libndksetup.so
/Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk/ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /Users/michal/Desktop/NDKSetup/obj/local/armeabi/objs/ndksetup/native.o: in function Java_com_example_ndksetup_MainActivity_printLog:/Users/michal/Desktop/NDKSetup/jni/native.c:11: error: undefined reference to 'av_register_all'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/Users/michal/Desktop/NDKSetup/obj/local/armeabi/libndksetup.so] Error 1
```

And I really dont know how to deal with it. Can you tell me what Im dooing wrong and how can I fix it? Or maybe there is another way to use .so library in Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LOCAL_SRC_FILES` in **Application.mk** does nothing. But you should add

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += avformat
```

to the **ndksetup** zection of your **Android.mk**.